# How to find case studies for your dissertation

Tags: thesis

I just wanted to know possible methods of finding some good case studies for a dissertation. I was asked to keep my question generic. I am doing a 1 year MA in Development Studies, specifically I want to look at Social Entrepreneurship. However, if one can tell how to find case studies on any topic, that would be helpful, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Center for the Advancement of Social Entrepreneurship(CASE), research and education center based at Duke University's Fuqua School of Business, has a number of case studies [here](http://www.caseatduke.org/knowledge/casestudies/index.html)

This [article](http://jab.sagepub.com/content/40/3/260.short) also was the first result in google scholar when searched.

Finally this [book](http://www.greenleaf-publishing.com/productdetail.kmod?productid=3353) *Case Studies in Social Entrepreneurship and Sustainability* might be an option.